# User:Stats No Longer displaying correct info for Member Types

Tags: solspace-user

I have a members area where the user can either be `Male/Female`, `Building Muscle/Losing Weight`, and either `Beginner/Intermediate/Advanced`

The way it worked before is if the user was a `Female`, trying to `Lose Weight`, and was a `Beginner` it would display content for that user.

**EDIT: Sorry I thought I mentioned the issue!  The problem is it will either display content randomly or nothing at all and I'm using User 3.4.5 and EE 2.7**
This is how the Supplement Section was coded:

```
{exp:user:stats}
    <ul id="membersboxes" class="block-grid three-up clearfix">
        <li>
            <div class="membersbox">       
                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Build Muscle" && member_level == "Beginner"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|43|45" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Build Muscle" && member_level == "Intermediate"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|43|46" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Build Muscle" && member_level == "Advanced"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|43|47" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Lose Weight" && member_level == "Beginner"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|44|45" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Lose Weight" && member_level == "Intermediate"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|44|46" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                {if member_gender == "Female" && member_goal == "Lose Weight" && member_level == "Advanced"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="supplement_guides"  category="42|44|47" dynamic="no" limit="1" status="open"}
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <p>{exp:trunchtml chars="150" inline="..."}{guide_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/if}

                <span class="seeall"><a href="{path='members-area/supplement-guides/'}">See All Supplement Guides</a></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
{/exp:user:stats}
```

This is just the supplements part of the female section, but for the entire code for Males/Females and including everything else you can visit [THIS LINK](http://d.pr/Iv4y)

Here is an image of the member fields:
[image: member fields]categories

Here is an image of the categories:[image: categories]

And here is how a user changes the type of member they are:[image: membertype]

And the code for that part of the settings page:

```
{exp:user:edit return="{path='member/updated-settings/'}"}
    <div class="settingswrap">
        <div class="membersheader">
            <h2>Current Level</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="member-settings">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select name="member_gender">
                {select_member_gender}
                <option value="{value}" {selected}>{value}</option>
                {/select_member_gender}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="member-settings">
            <label>Goal</label>
            <select name="member_goal">
                {select_member_goal}
                <option value="{value}" {selected}>{value}</option>
                {/select_member_goal}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="member-settings">
            <label>Level</label>
            <select name="member_level">
                {select_member_level}
                <option value="{value}" {selected}>{value}</option>
                {/select_member_level}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="save-settings">
            <input type="submit"  class="small blk button radius" name="submit" value="Save Settings" />
        </div>
    </div>
{/exp:user:edit}
```

It was working perfectly before.. not sure if the 2.7 update could of changed anything but I don't know what to do.

Please help if you can.. this site is suppose to go up soon and I don't know what to do

Comment: I might have missed it, but it would help to include your version of User and also what's wrong/changed with the output.

Comment: When you say User:Stats no longer displays the correct info, do you have any further info that can help clarify that? Is it a particular part in the "process" that seems to be the issue? If you create a new testing template and simplify your conditionals to just ONE conditional at a time, do they evaluate correctly? :)

Comment: @Solspace I tried just 1 conditional for each box but still no luck.. I also tried switching them to `{if}, {if:elseif}, {if:else}` conditionals

Answer (score 1):

I went in and also noticed that your entry was displayed, using on your {exp:channel:entries} code in the above first block of code, despite category 45, "Beginner", not being selected in the entry. However, I notice you are using

```
category="41|43|45"
```

...in `{exp:channel:entries}`. I assume in this case you want to have entries with categories 41 AND 43 AND 45, is that correct?
If so, you need this syntax:

```
category="41&43&45"
```

Here's the reference in the EE documentation: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category